# Error in installation Nodejs

Tags: python, node.js

I have a package node , I want to install it by usinge this commande :

```
./configure --prefix=/path/NODEJS/node_installation && make && make install
```

This will output the following error :

```
 File "./configure", line 16, in <module>
from gyp.common import GetFlavor
File "./tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
import gyp.input
File "./tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 873
except ImportError as e:
```

Helps appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: the problem was the version of python : NODEJS needs python 2.6 or 2.7 , , and me I had 2.5 . thank you @Dave